# How many skeletons do I need to kill to get level 30 in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

On average about how many skeletons do you need to kill to get from level 0 to level 30 in Minecraft?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Skeletons give 5 experience (and 1 to 3 depending on which weapon they spawned with)([Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Experience#Experience_amounts_by_source)). You need a total of 1395 experience for level 30 ([Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Experience#Leveling_up)). Assuming you get on average 7 experience, then in total you need to kill 1395 / 7 = **199 Skeletons**.

Comment: I am unsure what the chances are for the carried weapons, but a **minimum** of 1395 / 5 = **279 skeletons** is maybe also interesting to know

Comment: Is it not +2 experience per extra item they spawn with? i.e full armor= 8 + 5 experience?